# Android Activity — NullPointerException (unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo)

Tags: android, android-listview, parse-platform, nullpointerexception

I'm using Parse and I'm following a [tutorial](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-listview-images-and-texts-tutorial/) to create custom `listview` with images and texts . I am able to retrieve the images and texts in my listview . However, when I click on a listview item, it throws a null pointer exception instead of redirecting to a new activity and displaying specific results . I'm still unsure where I might have gone wrong.

The exception message :

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activityComponentInfo{com.androidbegin.parselistviewimgtxt/com.androidbegin.parselistviewimgtxt.SingleItemView}: java.lang.NullPointerException. 
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.androidbegin.parselistviewimgtxt.FileCache.<init>(FileCache.java:18)
    at com.androidbegin.parselistviewimgtxt.ImageLoader.<init>(ImageLoader.java:35)
    07-20 01:54:24.114: E/AndroidRuntime(1313):     at com.androidbegin.parselistviewimgtxt.SingleItemView.<init>(SingleItemView.java:16)
```

Here are the codes :

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
// Declare Variables
ListView listview;
List<ParseObject> ob;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
ListViewAdapter adapter;
private List<WorldPopulation> worldpopulationlist = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from listview_main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);
    // Execute RemoteDataTask AsyncTask
    new RemoteDataTask().execute();
}

// RemoteDataTask AsyncTask
private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

        // Set progressdialog title

        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create the array
        worldpopulationlist = new ArrayList<WorldPopulation>();
        try {
            // Locate the class table named "Country" in Parse.com
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                    "Country");
            // Locate the column named "ranknum" in Parse.com and order list
            // by ascending
            query.orderByAscending("ranknum");
            ob = query.find();
            for (ParseObject country : ob) {
                // Locate images in flag column
                ParseFile image = (ParseFile) country.get("flag");

                WorldPopulation map = new WorldPopulation();
                map.setRank((String) country.get("rank"));
                map.setCountry((String) country.get("country"));
                map.setPopulation((String) country.get("population"));
                map.setFlag(image.getUrl());
                worldpopulationlist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                worldpopulationlist);
        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }


}
}
```

**SingleItemView.java**

```
public class SingleItemView extends Activity {
    // Declare Variables
    String rank;
    String country;
    String population;
    String flag;
    String position;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(this);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from singleitemview.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.singleitemview);

    // Locate the TextViews in singleitemview.xml
    TextView txtrank = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rank);
    TextView txtcountry = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.country);
    TextView txtpopulation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.population);


    // Locate the ImageView in singleitemview.xml
    ImageView imgflag = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.flag);


    Intent i = getIntent();
    // Get the result of rank
    rank = i.getStringExtra("rank");
    // Get the result of country
    country = i.getStringExtra("country");
    // Get the result of population
    population = i.getStringExtra("population");
    // Get the result of flag
    flag = i.getStringExtra("flag");


    // Set results to the TextViews
    txtrank.setText(rank);
    txtcountry.setText(country);
    txtpopulation.setText(population);

    // Capture position and set results to the ImageView
    // Passes flag images URL into ImageLoader.class
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(flag, imgflag);
}
```

**ListViewAdapter.java**

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

// Declare Variables
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
ImageLoader imageLoader;
private List<WorldPopulation> worldpopulationlist = null;
private ArrayList<WorldPopulation> arraylist;

public ListViewAdapter(Context context,
        List<WorldPopulation> worldpopulationlist) {
    this.context = context;
    this.worldpopulationlist = worldpopulationlist;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList<WorldPopulation>();
    this.arraylist.addAll(worldpopulationlist);
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
}

public class ViewHolder {
    TextView rank;
    TextView country;
    TextView population;
    ImageView flag;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return worldpopulationlist.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return worldpopulationlist.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        holder.rank = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rank);
        holder.country = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.country);
        holder.population = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.population);
        // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
        holder.flag = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.flag);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    // Set the results into TextViews
    holder.rank.setText(worldpopulationlist.get(position).getRank());
    holder.country.setText(worldpopulationlist.get(position).getCountry());
    holder.population.setText(worldpopulationlist.get(position)
            .getPopulation());
    // Set the results into ImageView
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(worldpopulationlist.get(position).getFlag(),
            holder.flag);
    // Listen for ListView Item Click
    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Send single item click data to SingleItemView Class
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, SingleItemView.class);
            // Pass all data rank
            intent.putExtra("rank",
                    (worldpopulationlist.get(position).getRank()));
            // Pass all data country
            intent.putExtra("country",
                    (worldpopulationlist.get(position).getCountry()));
            // Pass all data population
            intent.putExtra("population",
                    (worldpopulationlist.get(position).getPopulation()));
            // Pass all data flag
            intent.putExtra("flag",
                    (worldpopulationlist.get(position).getFlag()));
            // Start SingleItemView Class
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

I tried

```
    if (getIntent().getStringExtra("rank") != null && (getIntent().getStringExtra("country") != null)&& (getIntent().getStringExtra("population") != null)&& (getIntent().getStringExtra("flag") != null)){

        rank = bundle.getString("rank");
        // Get the result of country
        country = bundle.getString("country");
        // Get the result of population
        population = bundle.getString("population");
        // Get the result of flag
        flag = bundle.getString("flag");

  }
```

Comment: Where have you set the value in `ob`? When you call those methods on `ob` in the `doInBackground()` method, ob is not even initialized. Hence null.

Comment: check getIntent() . you are getting null there

Comment: i tried checking for null values at getIntent() but it still throws the same exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should put the initialization of `ImageLoader imageLoader` in `SingleItemView` into the `onCreate` method above where before you use it `imageLoader.DisplayImage(flag, imgflag);`.

It may look like this

```
public class SingleItemView extends Activity {
    // Declare Variables
    String rank;
    String country;
    String population;
    String flag;
    String position;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from singleitemview.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.singleitemview);

        // Locate the TextViews in singleitemview.xml
        TextView txtrank = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rank);
        TextView txtcountry = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.country);
        TextView txtpopulation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.population);


        // Locate the ImageView in singleitemview.xml
        ImageView imgflag = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.flag);


        Intent i = getIntent();
        // Get the result of rank
        rank = i.getStringExtra("rank");
        // Get the result of country
        country = i.getStringExtra("country");
        // Get the result of population
        population = i.getStringExtra("population");
        // Get the result of flag
        flag = i.getStringExtra("flag");


        // Set results to the TextViews
        txtrank.setText(rank);
        txtcountry.setText(country);
        txtpopulation.setText(population);

        // Capture position and set results to the ImageView
        // Passes flag images URL into ImageLoader.class
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(this);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(flag, imgflag);
    }
```

Before `onCreate` the `Activity` may not have enough information that the `ImageLoader`'s constructor needs.